# job seek website database design

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a job seek website with PHP and MySQL, one question is how to design the database better? The basic function of the website is that 'jobseekers' can login and search jobs, upload CVs, and 'employers' can login and post jobs, and browser CVs. Currently I just created 2 tables:

```
-- Table structure for table users
to analyze the table sturctures for a job seek website(using MySQL and PHP) [on hold]

-- user_type: 0 - jobseekers
--            1 - employers
--            2 - administrator   

CREATE TABLE users (
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
pass CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
user_type TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
active CHAR(32),
last_login DATETIME NOT NULL,
registration_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
UNIQUE KEY (email),
INDEX login (email, pass)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


-- Table structure for table jobs

CREATE TABLE jobs (
job_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
description text NOT NULL,
county VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (job_id)
)  ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

But I feel just two tables might not be enough, and the user table maybe need to be broke down. Any suggestion how to improve the design?

Comment: The breadth and nature of this request falls foul of SO's policies, so I'll just say 'so far so good' (except that the job table is missing an employer_id). But you should also consider privacy and security. Who has access to what, and how is that controlled.

Comment: @user3205002.. rather than table structure post the er daigram ..for pointing out any redundancy.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you may want 4 tables;

2 to store the user details

jobseeker_details_table; ( name, address, phonenumber, CV etc)

employer_details_tabel; (name, address, companyname, phone, etc)

than 2 more tables, one for the jobs jobseekers have applied for, and one for the jobs employers have posted - as employers are likely to post more than one job position, and jobseekers and likely to apply for many different jobs, so;

jobs_applied_table; (id, jobid, status, etc)

employer_posted_jobs; (jobid, position_details, date_posted, status, etc)

hope that helps / gives you something to think about. 
good luck